# How to use less Activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I am very new to the Android programming scene, so I apologise if this is considered as a stupid question.

I am trying to develop a guide application that will contain many pages of information. I read somewhere that you should not have many Activities. So I was wondering if there were other ways to have lots of different pages of information, without using a lot of Activities.

Again, I apologise if this is considered really stupid or if there is a simple answer, but I don't know how to do such a thing.

Thanks in advance,

EDIT: Also, Is it possible to start an activity (via button press) and specify what view is shown in that activity from the activity containing the button?

Answer (score 1):

What is the data source of your information? Text files? If it's simply going to function as an e-reader, perhaps with some links, consider having a single "text view" activity, which, on specific triggers, loads up different data to display. This is a good alternative to have a separate activity for each "page" or "section" of your guide. I'd need to know a bit more about the source of your information you want to display, but I think you could adapt that concept to anything reasonable.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. It is mainly going to contain text, buttons (To go to another page) and images. It may contain a few tables, but that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

have your guide information in a parseable format. Your ONE activity generates the visible data based on what it parses.

so your "next page" button simply pulls information from next "Guide" object, and populates all the visual information with the elements of the Guide object.

Comment: I have separate xml files for each page, would it be best to use: `setContentView(R.layout.xmlfile);` ?

Comment: you may be able to inflate different views, but this certainly will happen in the same activity. if this fits your needs please upvote or mark as the best answer

Comment: Okay, thanks. Also, don't suppose it is possible to define a specific view to open rather than the default view in the OnCreate method through a button's OnClick method?

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to use a single activity with a WebView view, have your pages as HTML files under the assets directory (add there also any image files you need for the pages) and have in the HTML pages links or HTML buttons to navigate between the pages. If you need, you can also instruct from Java to load arbitrary pages. This way you will have rich format for your pages (HTML) and will need minimal programming.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that tip. I know enough HTML to probably be able to use that. Thanks again. :)